# How can I have jinja2 indentation and syntax when keeping HTML filetype?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, indentation

I have emmet installed and some more plugins that are usable on html filetypes, I would like to have syntax highlighting and have indentation for jinja2 while keeping the filetype HTML so my HTML plugins work as they have to.

Is there any work around for this?

PD: I have tried vim-jinja2-syntax but it doesn't recognize .html with jinja2 inside + it only highlights {} not the if, for ... (and this is only when setting filetype to jinja manually)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! More details may help (e.g., which plugins specifically). You can [edit] to add this. (You might try the "hidden magic" of multiple filetypes: `set filetype=html.jinja` or whatever. I suspect something will go haywire (syntax? indentation?), but plugins should be available.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `autocmd` to set the syntax to `htmldjango` when editing an HTML file:

```
autocmd FileType html set syntax=htmldjango
```

This preserves `filetype` while using the default `htmldjango` syntax file.

See:

```
:help :autocmd
:help 'syntax'
```